# Is "we can to make you" possible?

Tags: grammar

I said "Will I be alone?"
She said "Not at all, we will do anything we can to make you completely comfortable.
There will be more than enough staff to take care of all your needs."

I wonder "to" is correct or not in the second sentence.

Comment: You're just parsing the sentence slightly incorrectly.  "we can to make you" isn't one phrase.  The sentence is should be broken down like "We will do / anything we can / to make you completely comfortable."

Answer (score 1):

The use of "to" in the sentence beginning "Not at all..." is correct.  Stylistically, you might consider:

> "Will I be alone?" I asked.
>
> "Not at all," she responded, "we will do **everything** we can to make you completely comfortable.  There will be more than enough staff to take care of all your needs."

Note the emphasized word, "everything."  This is the more common word for this context.  Grammatically, "anything" is OK, it's just less commonly used this way and will therefore "sound funny" to some readers.

Answer (score 1):

This usage of “to” is common; it may be interpreted as “with the purpose of”:

We will do ***X*** to ***Y***

→ We will do ***X*** with the purpose of ***Y***

→ We will do ***anything we can*** with the purpose of ***making you completely comfortable***.

Answer (score 1):

make someone comfortable, tired, rich etc. is idiomatic.

To do everything for someone is fine. We will do everything to [etc.]

To do one's best for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your confusing.  In this sentence"We will do Everything We Can to make you completely comfortable." , the phrase "we can" here is to modify "everything" ,not another clause or subject and verb for "make you....".  You can delete the words "we can" and will not change the meaning.e.g."we can do everything to make you comfortable" .   By the way, "we can to make you comfortable " alone is definitely grammatically incorrect.